# Вставить число в свободный input

Tags: javascript, php

подскажите как вставлять числа в input по порядку нажатия

Есть к примеру 10 чисел и 3 input , при кликаньи на определенно число оно должно заносится в input

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

я нажал

**1** 2 3 **4** 5 6 7 8 **9** 10

и в трех input отобразилось

```
<input type="number" value="1">
<input type="number" value="4">
<input type="number" value="9">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так :

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]'),
  maxIndex = inputs.length - 1;
let currentIndex = 0;

[...document.getElementsByTagName('button')].forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const val = +e.target.textContent;
  inputs[currentIndex].value = val;
  currentIndex = currentIndex === maxIndex ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
}))
```

```html
<button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button><button>4</button><button>5</button><button>6</button><button>7</button><button>8</button><button>9</button>
<hr />
<input type="number" /><input type="number" /><input type="number" />
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое

Comment: @СтивенсонДейв не стоит благодарить, просто галку тикните и все )

Comment: ох а я всю страницу перерыл "где кнопка верный ответ ))"

Comment: А как сделать if что б нельзя было вводить одно и тоже число дважды а также если выбранно 3 числа у меня они активны становятся что бы убрать одно число и выбрать другое кнопка должна быть не активна

Comment: https://wampi.ru/image/6H0LNqH

Comment: туплю if я на php сделаю при отправке в базу